# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Google Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to call table chart using Google Chart Dashboard but I am getting this error. Not sure what is wrong with this. Even though the code is similar to my previous charts. Anything different with [Table Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="dashboard3_div">

                <div id="filter3_div"></div>
                <br />
                <div id="chart3_div"></div>
            </div>
```

**JS (Generated via C#)**

```
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawDashboard() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['ID', 'Time', 'Status', 'Assignee', 'DTime'],
// My data here

        ]);
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard3_div'));
        var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter3_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Assignee',
                'ui': {
                    'allowTyping': true,
                    'allowMultiple': false,
                    'allowNone': false,
                    'sortValues': false,
                }
            }
        });
        var table= new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'table',
            'containerId': 'Assignee',
        });

        dashboard.bind(slider, table);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Line 92 is         `dashboard.draw(data);`

Comment: where are you closing drawDashboard?

Comment: @madalinivascu That did the trick. I didn't close the drawDashboard tag !

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a couple typos...

first, make sure you're including the `'table'` package (not shown in question)
`packages: ['controls', 'table']`

next, `containerId` on the table looks off, it should match the `id` of  a `div`...

try --> `'containerId': 'chart3_div'`

instead of --> `'containerId': 'Assignee'`

lastly, the `chartType` needs to match the chart's class name
so `'table'` needs to be capitalized --> `'Table'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['ID', 'Time', 'Status', 'Assignee', 'DTime'],
        [0, '7:47 am', 'Testing', 'WhiteHat', '8:00 am']
    ]);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard3_div'));
    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'filter3_div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Assignee',
            'ui': {
                'allowTyping': true,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'allowNone': false,
                'sortValues': false,
            }
        }
    });
    var table= new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart3_div',
    });

    dashboard.bind(slider, table);

    // Draw the dashboard.
    dashboard.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard3_div">
    <div id="filter3_div"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="chart3_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `containerId` has to be the ID of the DOM element on your page that will host the control. I didn't close the drawDashboard tag hence I got the issue.

Comment: right, in your question, there is no DOM element with an ID of "Assignee" -- but the `ChartWrapper` for the `Table` chart has `'containerId': 'Assignee'` -- which will cause an error...

Comment: aah, must have made a wrong change while posting the code here.